# left and right arrow key problem using browser

Tags: browser

This is a common problem for firefox and google chrome.

When I want to navigate the webpage with the left and right arrow key, this happened:

I am in a forum, which of course have many pages. When I press the right arrow key, the browser jump to the next page automatically. When I press the left arrow key, the browser jump to the previous page automatically. This is not an expected behaviour, I expect it to navigate with the page left and right.

What's wrong?

Win xp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is entirely possible for JavaScript to capture the arrow key presses and navigate between pages using them; you will need to check if there is some setting on the site to disable it, or you will need to disable JavaScript for that site somehow.

Comment: After I turn off javascript, the problem went away, but it is nonsense to turn off javascript, and there is no a option to set a exception for a particular site, how-to?

Comment: There may be add-ons that can suppress it for specific sites.

Comment: OK, I installed an add-on "YesScript", it can disable JS for a site.